# Maximum Disc Coverage

Tags: java

We are supposed to find with every point (distance between two points must be <= 2) forming a circle, what is the maximum number of points that can be contained by a circle formed by these points. These points are stored in list. It just means among the list of points, we are supposed to pair two points together and see whether a circle forms by this 2 points can contain the most number of points. We are finding the most number of points.

Here is the code.

```
class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    Point (double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Point midPoint(Point q) {
        Point midPoint = new Point ((this.x + q.x)/2, (this.y + q.y)/2);
        return midPoint;
    }

    double distanceTo (Point q) {     
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((this.x - q.x), 2) + Math.pow((this.y - q.y),2));

    }

    double angleTo(Point q) {
        Point middlePoint = midPoint(q);
        return Math.atan2(middlePoint.x, middlePoint.y);
    }

    Point moveTo(double theta, double d) {
        Point newPoint = new Point ((this.x + d * Math.cos(theta)), this.y + d * Math.sin(theta));
        return newPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
       return "point (" +  String.format("%.3f",this.x) + ", " + String.format("%.3f", this.y) + ")"; 
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.List;

class Circle {
    private final Point centre;
    private final double radius;

    Circle (Point centre, double radius) {
        this.centre = centre;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    
    public int containsPoints (List<Point> points) {
        int numOfPoints = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i< points.size(); i++) {
            if (centre.distanceTo(points.get(i)) <= 2) {
                numOfPoints++;
            }
        }
        return numOfPoints;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "circle of radius " + this.radius + " centered at " + this.centre;
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.List;

Circle createUnitCircle(Point p, Point q) {
    double anglePQ = p.angleTo(q);
    Point midPoint = p.midPoint (q);
    double pqDistance = p.distanceTo(q);
    double mqDistance = midPoint.distanceTo(q);
    double dSquare = 1 - Math.pow(mqDistance, 2);
    double d = Math.sqrt (dSquare);

    Point centre = midPoint.moveTo(anglePQ, d);
    return new Circle (centre, 1);
}

int findMaxDiscCoverage (List<Point> points) {
    int maxDiscCoverage = 0;
    int numOfPoints = points.size();
    int numOfPointsContained = 0; 
     
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numOfPoints; j++) {
            Point point1 = points.get(i);
            Point point2 = points.get(j);
            if (point1.distanceTo(point2) > 2) {
                continue;
            }
           Circle c1 = createUnitCircle(point1, point2);
           numOfPointsContained = c1.containsPoints(points);
           if (numOfPointsContained > maxDiscCoverage) {
               maxDiscCoverage = numOfPointsContained;
           }
    return maxDiscCoverage;
}
```

I keep getting error like this

```
|  Error:
|  cannot find symbol
|    symbol:   method findMaxDiscCoverage(java.util.List<Point>)
|  findMaxDiscCoverage(points)
|  ^-----------------^
```

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: You cannot have methods outside of a class in Java. So your `createUnitCircle` and `findMaxDiscCoverage` are syntax errors.

Comment: oh that's weird as the school tasks us to write this jsh. but thanks you for your reply!